# How can I increase the number of threads running in my process?

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads, parallel-processing

I'm just playing around with threads to get used to them, so I wanted to make 20 threads that are all alive at the same time, and wrote this program:

```
static void * threadFunc(void *str)
{
    sleep(5);
}

int main (int argc, char * argv[])
{

    pthread_t arr[20];

    for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
        pthread_create(&arr[i], NULL, threadFunc, (void*)NULL);
        cout << "i=" << i << "\ntotal threads=" << pthread_is_threaded_np() << "\n";
    }
}
```

But it keeps saying total number of threads is 1.  What am I missing here?

Comment: Unrelated to threading, but you're overflowing your buffer. your loop should be `for (int i=0; i<20; i++)`, or else your buffer should be `pthread_t arr[21];` (as-is, you're trying use 21 values, but have an array of only 20).

Comment: @JerryCoffin: Now the OP has 22 problems!

Comment: i had a different value in there, just changed it when i copied it here.  i'll fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you think `pthread_is_threaded_np()` does?  Here's a hint: it's not what you want.

Comment: ooh oops.  i forgot, i tried using pthread_is_multithreaded_np() but it said it was undeclared.  is that what i need?

Comment: What do you think that function does?  Do you have a link to its documentation?

Comment: i was looking at this http://cursuri.cs.pub.ro/~apc/2003/resources/pthreads/uguide/users-24.htm#318361

Comment: Sure, so the "multi" version of the function might do what you want, but it doesn't exist on your platform (you haven't told us what system you're using).  And the non-multi version is documented as not doing what you want.  Both of them are marked "np" for non-portable, meaning that you probably shouldn't rely on them unless you absolutely must.

Comment: what are my options for finding out then using linux?

Comment: Who cares?  You create the threads, you know how many there are.  I understand you're just doing this as an exercise, but real code usually doesn't need to query the current number of threads inside its process.  I'd ignore this and move along.  Oh, and by the way, you could use Boost Thread, which has a thread pool, to create your 20 threads if you want (it even keeps a size() method for you to remind you in case you forget how big it is).

Comment: unfortunately i have to use pthread for class.  I just wanted to experiment with what happened as the number of threads approached the maximum, so i wanted to be able to tell if they were actually still alive.  i duno.  still learning threads.

Comment: what about for debugging purposes?  say i want to see if my threads are being terminated properly?  then I'd need to know how many there are, right?

Comment: In that case just use an outside tool like `ps -L` which will show you your threads, or use a debugger, etc.

Comment: i found it in activity monitor, just double clicking on the process brings it up.